# Lenovo z580 bluetooth does not work

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

I have Windows 10 on my laptop Lenovo Z580.

I have a problem with the Bluetooth connection, I want to connect a keyboard, but nowhere can I find the settings for the Bluetooth connection.

I have installed the drivers and nothing happens. I checked the BIOS and Bluetooth is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting 3 days I found that Updating BIOS is only way to Restore Bluetooth.
I may sound Odd but, I tried in every way.

The only way your left is to update BIOS.